# Letter writer snapped at my reminder email. What can I do in the future to prevent this, and should I still accept his letter?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, recommendation-letter, interpersonal-issues

I sent a reminder email one day before the due date for a couple of my applications to grad school. It said something along the lines of

> This is just a reminder that first due dates are tomorrow: [list of a
>   couple of schools]. Hope you aren't too busy to write still. If you
>   haven't received an email from these schools on instructions let me
>   know.

I also sent "resends" to this professor's email via the schools' application portals. The professor responded with something like

> You've already sent a list of deadlines [I did, but this was about a
>   month ago]. It is NOT helpful to send repeated reminders.

I thought it was standard to send reminders before deadlines, especially if due dates are tomorrow with no letter sent. I feel that I have said or done something wrong. **How can I prevent this from happening in the future?**

I am now not only reluctant to send reminders for January schools, but I am now worried about the strength of this professor's letter. I have four letter writers, and I am tempted to drop his letter on some January schools. The reason for this is that this is not the only time he has been a bit snappy with me, although never like this. But I did tell him a while ago that I did not want his letter if it would not be strong, and yet he still agreed to write for me. So assuming he is honest about that, I feel I should maybe keep his letter.

This is all a little confusing and stressful. Thanks for your time to read.

Comment: One way to make your message seem less micromanaging and more proactive, is to ask if there is anything that your letter writer might need from you, or if there is anything you can do.  This is a gentle way of saying "It's getting close to the deadline, and I realize that you are busy, so I'm just letting you know that I am happy to help you in any way that I can because I really appreciate your willingness to help me."  This way shows that you are paying attention to detail, wanting to make the process as easy for them as possible, but still respectful of doing things their way.

Comment: _It is not helpful to send repeated reminders._ — Oh, yes, it is.

Comment: I wouldn't describe that as "snapping." Mild annoyance at worst.

Comment: @JeffE It is so helfpul to receive repeated reminders that countless people world round use software to inflict it on themselves. Doctors' receptionists call people 24 in advance of appointments, why? Because it works in reducing no-shows. How can that prof say something  so utterly silly.

Comment: This isn't a real problem, forget about it, nothing to worry about. Noone knows if he 'snapped', that's your inference. It looks polite to me. Presumably he is being bugged by other candidates too. Certainly he didn't go full Robert de Niro or Joe Pesci. It is good that he is organized enough to not need a reminder. So stop worrying and no need to stress. (If you *really* wanted, if you decided to send this sort of reminder in future you could say *"Apologies if this reminder is unnecessary and I appreciate your current mail volume must be high, but here's a reminder that..."*)

Comment: Here is what I did when I needed letters. When someone agreed to write me a reference letter, I immediately asked explicitly "The deadline is in such and such, should I send you reminders every so often?", on one occasion, the answer was "daily reminders, please" and on another "if you haven't heard from me in two weeks, please remind me". This way you can know in advance whether or not you even need to remind people, and how often.

Comment: @jpmc26 Perhaps, yes. I did change what he actually wrote for anonymity. He actually capitalized "not", as to emphasize that he was annoyed. Edited for accuracy.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> I feel that I have said or done something wrong. How can I prevent
>   this from happening in the future?

The only odd thing you did was remind via *both* the online system and the personal email without acknowledging you did so in the email ("I am writing you an email on top of the online notices because I was told those sometimes get caught in spam.")

You could follow up with: "My apologies. I wanted to put the links at the top of your inbox so you could find them easily. I thought I should follow up with an email because I was told these can sometimes go to spam. I realize now this could be a bit obnoxious. Thanks again for your willingness to write a letter." You might stop by later and find out if he doesn't want ANY reminders or if he just wants a single one from the online system or a single one via personal email.

> I am now worried about the strength of this professor's letter. I have
>   four letter writers, and I am tempted to drop his letter on some
>   January schools.

I would say you need to figure out if his behavior with you is just his typical behavior, or if he acts more negatively toward you than toward other students in your position. It seems most relevant to figure out your position relative to HIS baseline, not relative to a "nice person."

Comment: To emphasize this last part of the answer more: interpersonal skills are about calibration - both tuning your behavior to what works best with that person specifically, and also tuning your interpretation of that person's actions to take into account how that person normally thinks/acts/behaves.

Answer (score 73):

> How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Well, you can always go live on a desert island, or join an order of silent monks (and even living among monks would not guarantee that you will escape such foibles of human nature).

More seriously: you can’t prevent it, and you shouldn’t try either. You did absolutely nothing wrong by sending a reminder email. For every professor who responds irritably to your emails there are at least ten others who would appreciate your reminder email, and for some of them the reminder would even be needed to get them to upload their letter. Thus, you stand to lose much more than you will gain by changing your behavior because of the professor’s response. Just accept that working with other people necessitates occasionally having some strange and perhaps unpleasant interactions (trust me, you will have many more), and move on.

By the way, I also think it’s highly unlikely that the professor will modify his recommendation because of your email — that would be an extremely unprofessional and unethical thing to do, much more so than replying irritably to an email. Anyway, good luck with your applications.

Comment: This was my thought exactly - right now is just a busy time for professors (and everyone, really) so he's probably irritated at other things and this was just a small piece of steam to vent.

Comment: "Professors are human" strikes again.

Comment: Joining that order of silent monks might, in fact, expose you to certain other "foibles of human nature"...

Comment: @gerrit: "Professors are socially inept humans" perhaps :)

Answer (score 24):

> This is just a reminder that first due dates are tomorrow: [list of a couple of schools]. Hope you have time to write still. If you haven't received an email from these schools on instructions let me know.

This wasn't worded very well.  By explicitly declaring your message a "*reminder*", you've:

1. Taken a role in managing their activities.
2. Suggested that you have less than perfect confidence in their reliability.

In general, both of these things might inspire offense.  The primary issue is that, as a student requesting a recommendation letter, you're making a request of a professional-superior; deference and thanks are the typical expectations.

So, you'd have two ways to approach this: either as a professional-peer trying to coordinate an activity or a professional-subordinate requesting guidance from a superior.

To word something like this as a professional-peer:

> I'm working on finalizing my applications to [list of schools] that have their deadlines tomorrow, so I just wanted to touch base with you on the recommendation letters and thank you again for your time and consideration.  Please let me know if they failed to send you the invitation via email or if there's anything else that I could do on my end.

To word something like this as a professional-subordinate:

> Thank you for helping me with the application process with your recommendation.  Since a few of the deadlines are tomorrow, I'm trying to make sure that I got everything in order, including ensuring that I properly provided those kind enough to provide recommendation letters with access to the applications.  Please let me know if there's anything else that I need to do, and thank you for your time and consideration!

Whether you approach a recommendation-writer as a peer or subordinate will depend on a lot of personal factors, so that's a case-by-case thing.

Stuff to avoid:

1. **"Reminding" them.**  Reminding someone suggests that you're not 100% confident that they were on-track.  However plausible or reasonable this might be, some might still take offense to it.
2. **Managing their activities.**  In some sense, they've agreed to do something for you, and thus you might reasonably argue that they're obligated to perform the agreed-upon service.  And while this might seem technically true, it'll often rub people the wrong way; it's best to avoid sounding like a micro-manager.

Comment: I had not thought about it that way. I guess there are more subtleties and etiquette to these things than I thought. Personally, I would not have taken an email like mine with offense, as it is just a formal reminder. I will keep this in mind for next time, thanks.

Comment: @Fred Definitely.  And just to mention it, the objective tone that you'd used would work with a lot of folks, so I guess that it's a situational thing.

Comment: I suppose it's a matter of taste and/or culture, but (as someone who has written letters for students) I find OP's message direct and to-the-point, and I find yours sycophantic and insincere. No matter how it's phrased, it IS a reminder, so I see no point in avoiding the word.

Comment: @user37208 Agreed that it'll vary with taste or/and culture.  I can definitely see how the professional-subordinate message could come off as sycophantic, though would you take issue with the professional-peer one?

Comment: @Nat Less so, but they both come across a bit passive-aggressive to me, because they dance around the actual message being conveyed.

Comment: @user37208 I can definitely see how this would sound like a very wordy approach to providing a reminder, and I certainly agree that the objective tone the OP used in their email would be more concise and efficient, which could be taken as a sign of respect for the recommendation-writer's time.  Where's the passive-aggressive part come in?

Comment: I completely agree with @user37208 that your suggested letters come across as sycophantic and insincere. Also, _Please let me know if there's anything else that I need to do_ just makes things worse by burdening the letter-writer with another (completely pointless and made-up) task that should not be their responsibility. As a letter-writer myself, I absolutely want the student to give me instructions (as clear and direct as possible) about what they need me to do, and conversely would be greatly annoyed if the student were to ask _me_ to give _them_ instructions, which is totally not my job.

Comment: I agree that *Please let me know if there's anything else that I need to do* because we all know that the ball is in the professor's court.  To somewhat press the point, you could say *Please let me know if you're no longer able to write a letter.*  I would never bail out at the deadline like that, but it does frame the choice starkly: write the letter now, or I'll need to start looking for another letter writer.

Comment: On the other hand, I like beginning with *Thank you* [*again*, I would add] *for helping me with the application process with your recommendation.*  People like to be asked and they liked to be thanked.

Comment: @DanRomik: That's totally not how I read Nat's suggested phrasing, but you've got a point that it could be read that way. Maybe something like *Please let me know if I've neglected to provide any relevant information, or if there's anything else I can do that would be helpful to you* would be better?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yes, that is indeed better (and is similar to the language at the end of Nat’s first suggested letter).

Comment: +1. I actually found OP's original letter as weird, and slightly rude (especially "I hope you aren't too busy to write still", which feels like sarcasm, but maybe this is just me). The suggestion in this answer looks better, which the comments further improve.

Answer (score 16):

My wife has a saying: "Everyone has their own bucket of [*fecal matter*]".

It's easy to take this at face value and react.  If you've got experience with this person and he's always an obnoxious turd, that's one thing; on the other hand, if he's not normally like this, he might have been having a bad day and lashed out.  Can you communicate with him directly?  Consider dropping by for a cup of coffee, see if you can find out if he's having personal issues, talk to him directly and see what the issue really is.  Remember, email truly *sucks* as a communication device for anything other than cold, dry facts.

If he's just not going to put in the work, and he lets you down, you will know better than to depend on him next time.

Comment: This is a great idea. My anxiety is at peak lately and it's tough to think things like this through. Good advice, thanks.

Comment: _see if you can find out if he's having personal issues_ - I am not really sure if that is what students are supposed to do.

Answer (score 9):

One trick we had back in the day for *exactly* this situation was (a benign abuse of):

### The thank-you note.

Instead of a reminder, which, as you have experienced firsthand, can be interpreted as pushy, send a note expressing your gratitude the professor for having written the letter on your behalf despite the "short deadline of X", and how much that means to you. Written properly, such a note can't be construed as inappropriately pushy.

If they have written the letter, they will get a warm fuzzy feeling.

If they haven't, then unless they're sociopathic (in which case you probably don't want their letter anyway), they will get some serious cognitive dissonance at not having written or sent it yet, and then most likely proceed to do so immediately. After which they will get the warm fuzzy feeling.

Everybody wins.

Comment: As with the other approaches advocating dishonest (if well-intentioned) methods, the expected “warm fuzzy feeling” could well turn out instead to be annoyance and resentment on the professor’s part at being manipulated and lied to, however “benignly”. Sorry, I simply don’t buy your claim that “written properly, such a note can’t be construed as inappropriately pushy”; for me, the best warm fuzzy feelings I get is when people are being honest with me rather than trying to manipulate me in a cheap, transparent way as if I was some kind of marionette on a string.

Comment: @DanRomik I disagree. I think your use of the word "dishonest" is pushing its definition to its literal extreme, where it in fact turns into the concept of "politeness", which is, if one insists on interpreting things in a negative light, indeed a form of dishonesty.

Answer (score 7):

**Just apologize and move on.** No need to skip his letter. It sounds like you're moving on soon enough and won't have to deal with his snippy personality much more.

Some professors have asked me to send them reminders because they're busy, and so I do. You're not *really* in the wrong having done this, unless he explicitly asked you not to. Apologizing costs nothing and just greases the wheels. Sounds like this professor does a good job of staying organized (or thinks he does). Some professors get hundreds of emails a day, and he was probably annoyed at one more (two more?) email(s) telling him something he already knew.

Now the question is whether you send the apology by email ...

Comment: Maybe an apology isn't needed at all. The professor might be in over his head with writing too many letters too close to the deadline and snapped due to stress. Maybe the professor just needs a bit of quiet to get the letters done. We all snap sometimes, hopefully we snap at people we can make it up to and who can forgive us.

Comment: @Bent An apology is an expression of forgiveness?

Comment: The professor should perhaps apologize at a later stage, not the OP. I wouldn't apologize to the professor, nor would I mention anything as long as the letters gets send on time. OP should not apologize, if in OP's situation I would forgive the professor as long as the letters are sent. In the western world if you apologize you are the one that needs to be forgiven. This is the other way round.

Comment: @Bent Respectfully, I disagree. The OP bothered their professor by sending them an extra email. Sometimes you have to swallow your pride (did the professor overreact? yeah, a little bit) and smooth things over by taking the high road and apologizing for upsetting someone. In a perfect world, yes, the professor would apologize for snapping. But this isn't a perfect world.

Comment: I think the question is not so much whether the student has a moral imperative to apologize (it sounds like you agree that he doesn’t, since he didn’t do anything wrong), but whether it would be strategically beneficial for him to apologize. On that question, I would argue that when someone snaps at you irritably for sending him too many emails, the last thing you would want to do is to bother him with yet another email apologizing for all the previous emails...

Comment: @DanRomik I agree that there is a moral versus strategy problem and I think we agree on the moral part.  It is not obvious on strategy.  (1) "The squeaky wheel gets the grease." versus (2) The prof in bad mood writes weak reference.

Comment: @DanRomik To me it's just about navigating the power relationship and taking a hit to your pride to get what you need (a good letter). No, don't send an email that's nothing but "sorry for all the emails," but you could express your apology in person, or with another necessary email, or in all sorts of other ways.